# Trouble upgrading

Tags: ee2, solspace-calendar, ee2-upgrades

I have a client site on EE 2.5.3 platform and Solspace Calendar 1.7.0. Obviously this should be upgraded, but when I try to upgrade to EE 2.9.0 the whole thing stops around version 2.6-2.7 with this error message:

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'protect_javascript' in 'field list'
UPDATE `exp_templates` SET `template_id` = '33', `site_id` = '1', `group_id` = '4', `template_name` = 'edit', `save_template_file` = 'n', `template_type` = 'webpage', `template_data` = '{embed=\"calendar_inc/index\" page_title=\"Edit Event\"}\n\n\n{exp:calendar:datepicker_js}\n{exp:calendar:datepicker_css}\n\n\n{embed=\"calendar_inc/header\"}\n\n

I'm unable to log on after this error, and have to restore both site and database from backup.

My question is: what is the recommended approach to upgrade both EE and Calendar here? The latest version of Calendar (1.8.9) requires EE 2.6, but upgrading of EE from v. 2.5.3 stops and breaks on the old Calendar module (1.7.0).

I hope I have been clear – and that someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: It's the other way around: **EE 2.6 requires Calendar 1.8.4 (and up)** for Calendar to work under that EE version. For EE 2.9, you need Calendar 1.8.9 and up. I assume you're referring to the compatibility chart found here: http://www.solspace.com/software/compatibility
The versions of our add-ons for each EE versions are the **minimum versions required for the add-on to work under the EE version** you are currently using.

Comment: This means that you could use 1.8.9 and up and it should work with your version of EE (EE 2.9 for example).
Of course, we have a range of EE versions that we support, which means that if your version of EE is lower than this range, the add-on would likely work with its latest version, but we can't guarantee it. We strongly recommend making backups and testing the add-on before applying on a live site.

Comment: That said, do what is usually recommended with any add-on (not just Solspace's): 1. Backup everything, 2. _Strongly_ consider testing the upgrade on a test/development/versioned installation, 3. upgrade add-ons **first**, 4. **then** upgrade EE. Hope this gets you through.

Comment: Next, the error mentions `exp_templates`, which is a native EE table, which _happens_ to contain Calendar template code. It could be that Calendar isn't involved. I also can't find a `protect_javascript` column in `exp_templates`. Could another add-on have added this column? In fact, `protect_javascript` is a config.php value: http://familysunshine.org/docs/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html#protect_javascript Maybe change the value and see how that goes?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, and I apologize for double posting. This cleas it up for me – I was a bit confused about the compatibility charts, as I read another place that Calendar version 1.8.4 REQUIRES EE 2.6. Off we go then, starting with upgrading the module(s) on EE 2.5.x and then EE to 2.9.x. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Hi again, I need to ask again about this matter, regarding module updates. I notice that you can't guarantee that the latest versions ov Calendar and Freeform (not pro) will work on EE 2.5.2 – would it be possible to another, earlier versoin of these two modules and then perform a step-by-step upgrade of EE – just to get EE up to 2.6 or later, which Solspace support? Thanx in advance – for any response.

Comment: Yeah, you can try that if you want (incremental upgrades). **Make backups and test on a local/dev/experimental installation**. Still think the issue is likely not Calendar-related though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going to be difficult.

Perhaps the best way to approach it would be to update EE from 1.7.0 to an early version of 2. Then upgrade calendar and ensure it's working. Only then try to upgrade to the more recent version of EE.

Comment: Thanks for your response – it looks I haven't been as clear as I hoped; I currently have EE 2.5.3 and Solspace Calendar 1.7.0...

Comment: Sorry, you were clear, I just didn't read your question properly! If it's failing when you upgrade from EE2.5.3 to EE2.6 then I think the only option is to remove Calendar, do the updates then reinstall it.

Comment: Uninstalling a module (any/most modules, not only Solspace's) will make you lose all settings, configurations, and data for that module. Unless you don't mind losing the data (or the add-on doesn't hold much data/settings), I wouldn't recommend doing this as an initial approach.